# Does pybind11 default arugments expression been called every time when the python API been invoked?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to add an expression as default arguments to my python function API, which is implemented by pybind11.

For example, here's the C++ function:

```
void my_print(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now()) {
  std::cout << tp << std::endl;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {
  m.doc() = "my python module implement in pybind11";
  m.def("my_print", &my_print, py::arg("tp") = std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

Now I'm wonderring that, the expression `= std::chrono::system_clock::now()`, I want it been called everytime I invoke this `my_print` API in python script.

But I'm not sure, is this expression been called everytime this API been invoked in python ? Or this expression is only been called once when this python module been load in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is evaluated once, during the (runtime) initialization of the pybind bindings.

The way this feature is implemented is by [overloading `operator=`](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/39fbc7992b28188aac6bbcfa7d7814b217f54674/include/pybind11/cast.h#L1100) of `py::arg` to return a different type, `py::arg_v` (short for argument with default value).

Comment: is there a way to bind a lambda to default argument? so everytime I call the python api, the lambda in default argument is been called?

Comment: Not that I know